# Implement the images from my drawable folder to List

Tags: android

Instead of opening the images from these url's given bellow  how can i implement-open images from my drawable folder? I tried replacing the Url with ("drawable/img.jpg") with no luck.

```
public void startGalleryActivity() {
    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
      images.add("http://sourcey.com/images/stock/salvador-dali-persistence-of-memory.jpg");
    images.add("http://sourcey.com/images/stock/salvador-dali-the-dream.jpg");


    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(GalleryActivity.EXTRA_NAME, images);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `R.drawable` values are integers, use `putIntegerArrayListExtra()`:

```
public void startGalleryActivity() {
    ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<>();
    images.add(R.drawable.image_one);
    images.add(R.drawable.image_two);
    // and so on

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(GalleryActivity.EXTRA_NAME, images);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: First of all,thank you very much for your answer. I get an exception and a message"too much output to process ",then the app crashes immediately.It's weird because i've tried with only one image of 200Kilobytes. Before the change,with the url's,the app was running perfect. Anyway i am gonna keep checking,thanks again :)